# Display more than focused EditText in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to display more than focused EditText while virtual keyboard is activated in landscape orientation?

Before keyboard is activated:
[image: Before focus]

When virtual keyboard is activated:
[image: After focus]

For example above: is it possible to display "Hello world!" and editbox when keyboard is activated?

Comment: what do you mean by `more than focused` ??

Comment: please check images I added...

Comment: try this `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` for your `editText`

Comment: I do not try this! But good to know it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` for your editText